# Union with omit

Tags: typescript

[Look at the following snippet of code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAHgHgCoBoDSA%20GBeGBvYGGAQxgC4ZUZCYAjcmAClIqQEocs1gBfAbmrBQkWGGTosuAPIBbAJYgEiVJhQByWmqwAfeOMxDgAYwD2AOwDOIGDLAA1YgCc5xWgBsoFMVedmA5ihmAK4ytFCOkvhELDBqFiYyUADKIL5%20aij0FMwMPnL%20HNhYAIwwPEKmlta2AGJBZkYgcuY4MABm9Y3NZox4xJk8DN6p%20QHBoeEYbHjlQA). It might look strange but it is useful in specific cases. But for clarity of problem I post it in simplified form.

```
type x<T,K> = {
  a : T, 
  b : (a : T) => K
}; 


type y<T,K> = Omit<x<T,K>,'b'> | x<T,K>


const myVariable: y<string,number> = {  a : 'someString',b : (a : string) => 1 }

const myFunction = function({a,b} : y<string,number>){}
```

Two last lines look to me like a bug in TypeScript. `myVariable` is of type `y<string,number>` and everything works fine, property `b` exists on the this type. But last line throws error which says `Property 'b' does not exist on type 'y<string, number>'` Isn't this a contradiction?

Comment: FWIW, `myVariable` doesn't have a `b` member either, according to TS Playground.

Comment: @Dai what do you mean? In the playground myVariable has b. What version of ts you used in playground? Did it throw you some error? For me line `const myVariable: y<string,number> = {  a : 'someString',b : (a : string) => 1 }
` compiles. And without any problem i can call `myVariable.b('whatever')`

Comment: First-off, please do not use short, cryptic names like `x` and `y` - I've renamed them in a Playground copy (see comment below) and it makes the issue easier to see: the problem _isn't_ that `myVariable`'s type lacks a `b` member, but that the `y` type _might_ have a `b` member (as it's a union-type). Hence why your `{a,b}` unpacked parameter is invalid because TS knows that `y` _might_ have a `b` member, but `{a,b}` _requires_ a `b` member.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsmAwgewLYQDZQB4B4AqANANIB8MAvDAN7AwwCGMAXDETHTAEYswAUTVvgCUlcsWABfANwdgoSLAQp0WbHAZguUAOoBLEAAtkAVxAAhAiXJUA8qgO54SNJhxWyhGAHIu3mOQAPs4qbnhEZNLywADGyAB2AM4gMKhgAGoMAE56DFxYrMquahpaugbGZpbJOfEA5oTxJqjaWTY0nPSCPoloUADKILV13oSd3LwCvDV69aIU5ACMUtFxSSlpAGIm8TEgegmUMABmO3sH8Xw0DIRckrxFqjil2vpGpha4M-WNza3kolokmAQA

Comment: What do you mean by "mathematically"? If you're referring to _type theory_ then I'll say it makes sense to me. Are you getting thrown-off by what a type-union means? Remember that Type-Unions are _not_ Set-Unions and Types are not Sets.

Comment: @Dai what do you mean by `but {a,b} requires a b member.  ` means that those are allowed keys, if required it will be know later. `const myFunction =  function({ a,b} : {a : string, b? : string})` You can call it by `myFunction({ a : 'blah'})`

Comment: No, that's not what `{a,b}` means. It means `a` and `b` **must be present** in the object before it's destructured into separate `a` and `b` locals.

Comment: You can call it and it will work, yes - but that doesn't mean your type-annotations and destructured parameter is _correct_.

Comment: What do you mean by 'correct'? if typescript compiles, and do not throw the error then it is correct right

Comment: Your code _doesn't compile_ though.... (Also, haven't you read my posted answer yet?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251980/discussion-between-chilly-maximus-and-dai).

Comment: It appears you left the chat-room you created before I even got there myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are seeing is not a bug in TypeScript, but rather a result of the way the `y` type is defined.

When you define `myVariable` as `y<string,number>` and include the `b` property, TypeScript is able to infer the correct type. However, when you pass myVariable to a function expecting a `y<string,number>`, TypeScript checks the type compatibility, and because the function could receive an object of type `y<string,number>` that does not have the b property, it throws an error.

One solution to this issue is to use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html). This allows you to explicitly inform TypeScript that the b property exists.

```
function hasB<T, K>(obj: y<T, K>): obj is x<T, K> {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty('b') ;
}

function myFunction(obj: y<string, number>) {
  if (hasB(obj)) {
    console.log(obj.b)
    // obj has a b property, so we can safely access it
  }
  console.log(obj.a);
}
```

In general, you don't necessarily need to create your own type guard. TypeScript has built-in mechanisms for checking if a type is compatible with another type. For example `in` keyword to checks whether the args object has a property `b`:

```
function myFunction(obj: y<string, number>) {
  if ('b' in obj) {
    console.log(obj.b)
    // obj has a b property, so we can safely access it
  }
  console.log(obj.a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is easier to read if you use verbose, instead of short cryptic names:

- Rename `x<T,K>` to `MyComplex<T,K>`
- Add `type MyComplexWithoutB<T,K> = Omit< MyComplex<T,K>, 'b' >;`
- Rename `y<T,K>` to `MyComplex_or_MyComplexWithoutB<T,K>`
- Change `MyComplex_or_MyComplexWithoutB<T,K>`'s union to `MyComplexWithoutB<T,K> | MyComplex<T,K>`

Doing so gives us this:

```js
type MyComplex<T,K> = {
  a : T, 
  b : (a : T) => K
}; 

type MyComplexWithoutB<T,K> = Omit< MyComplex<T,K>, 'b' >;

type MyComplex_or_MyComplexWithoutB<T,K> = MyComplexWithoutB<T,K> | MyComplex<T,K>;

const myVariable: MyComplex_or_MyComplexWithoutB<string,number> = {
    a : 'someString',
    b : (a : string) => 1
}

const myFunction = function( {a,b} : MyComplex_or_MyComplexWithoutB<string,number> ) {
}
```

And so looking at the destructured parameter again, by using `{a,b}` it means that the parameter's argument **must** have both `a` and `b` members, but the `MyComplex_or_MyComplexWithoutB<string,number>` type **might not** have a `b` member, which means destructuring the parameter to `{a,b}` *under and and all circumstances* is impossible, hence the error.

---

One possible solution is to destructure only after you can prove to TypeScript that the argument *does* have a `b` member:

```js
const myFunction = function( arg: MyComplex_or_MyComplexWithoutB<string,number> ) {
    if( 'b' in arg ) {
        // i.e. `arg` is `MyComplex<string,number>`
        let { a, b } = arg;
    }
    else {
        // i.e. `arg` is `MyComplexWithoutB<string,number>>`
        let { a } = arg;
    }
}
```

[...which compiles just fine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAsmAwgewLYQDZQB4B4AqANANIB8MAvDAN7AwwCGMAXDETHTAEYswAUTVvgCUlcsWABfANwdg88NHhI0mHAHUAliAAWyAK4gAQgRLkqAeVTbcylOix4iZQjADkXNzFLSFkWAj2atgA%20sgATiGBqo5augbGpmSUdjEa2nqGJs7kAD6pDjhJPvIAxsgAdgDOIDCoYABqDOGaDFxYrNGFoRFRKt1xmYk1LRUA5oQV%20qhcUOHmNJz0gu5VaFAAyiCjY26ES9y8ArwjmuOiFOQAjFLyZZU1dWAAYvoVpSCalSkAZm8fXwqfEY4TGnX6wTCkS6wUGCRMp3Gk2ms3mMFEtHo9E0P2BHi8ZxBY3RiyxZJgAHoKTBNAA6KC0mAAA2aYyZNKqzJhjlwiImUxmc1ITIOZKwtWoDEIXEkKVZvjJkgOUAwVVgmPJ9CpNPpjJZoPZmk5TO56XiWWKIsVUiAA).